# Why linear model cannot understand the interaction between any two input features?

Tags: deep-learning, linear-algebra

The book Deep Learning by Ian Goodfellow states that:

```
Linear models also have the obvious defect that the model capacity is limited to 
linear functions, so the model cannot understand the interaction between any two 
input variables.
```

1. What is meant by "interaction between variables"
2. How do non linear models find it?

Would be great if someone can give an intuitive/graphical/geometrical explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine our model has two inputs `X1`, `X2` and one output `Y`  Our input variables "interact" if, for example, the effect that `X1` has on `Y` depends on the value of `X2`.

The simplest way to model an interaction term is by adding a term that has `X1 * X2`, for example:

`Y = a*X1 + b*X2 + c*X1*X2 + d`

The model above is non-linear in its inputs `X1`,`X2`: this is the kind of linearity Goodfellow is talking about. Note that it is linear in its parameters `a`,`,b`,`c` though, so you will still see this problem called "linear regression."

#### Example

Let's look at a specific example: [wikipedia's cookie baking data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)#Hypothesis_tests_for_interactions). Our inputs are `Temperature` and `time` (in the oven).  Our output is cookie `Yield`.

- Increasing `Temperature` *increases* cookie yield when `time` is short.
- Increasing `Temperature` *decreases* cookie yield when `time` is long.

Therefore the `Temperature` and `time` variables interact.

##### The interaction term

What does the interaction term (`X1*X2`) in the model do?

You can think of it as varying or interpolating between two simpler, one-variable models, using a second variable. If our two simple models are:

- Model A: `Y = a0 + a1 * Temperature`
- Model B: `Y = b0 + b1 * Temperature`

Then our full model, with interaction is:

`Y = c_0 + c_a * time * (Model A) + c_b * time (Model B)`

Try simplifying it, and you'll see that you get four terms that look like the first model we wrote down:

`Y = a*X1 + b*X2 + c*X1*X2 + d`

[image]